# HTTP compliance testing

Tags: python, http, testing, standards-compliance

What would you use to perform a compliance testing of an HTTP proxy? I've seen two projects so far:

- [Web Polygraph](http://www.web-polygraph.org/) (the feedback I got from a coworker is mostly negative)
- [Funkload](http://funkload.nuxeo.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: http://www.measurement-factory.com/

The Co-Advisor product might be what you are after. Note that this is by the same mob that created Web-Polygraph/